# I select multiple Elements when I click, now I want only one of them (click function similar to the inspector from the browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have currently a jquery selector on `$("body *")` so that I get the clicked elements of the page when I click somewhere. And I am also aware why I get more than 1 Element returned. (For example: If I click on a Button, also all parent Elements have the Click Event and are getting fired).

My Problem: I want a click function like the Inspector has. I only want the Element that I meant to click on. And when I watched the log, where I output all clicked elements, I noticed that the element, I wanted to click, is always the first that gets written in the console. So my first idea is now to just get rid of all elements except the first one but I don't know how to separate these. How can I access and edit/delete all clicked elements from `$(this)`?

Or is there another and better way to get the clicked element?

Code and Image:

```
$("body *").click(function (e) {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Now all Elements from the image up the tree get written in the console.

[image: outcome]

Comment: Could you put a demo in a JSfiddle? or on SO so we can take a look?

Comment: can you show some html+ script code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) which is the element that was actually clicked.

Edit:

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // target
    console.log($(this)); // body
});
```

That code will attach a click event handler to the body. The event will only fire once, rather than once per parent as was happening with the 'body *' selector. Then, you can use $(e.target) to get what was actually clicked on and $(this) will be the body and no extra parent elements will need to be dealt with.

Comment: `event.target` would give me the correct element but this would happen for all selected elements. The parents of a picture would normally return themself and with `event.target` I would get for every parent the element I really clicked. If you look at the image in my post there would now be written the correct element for every element that is currently there.

Comment: Oh, okay, I misunderstood your question at first. I'm not sure what your use case is for this and if you want all of those items to have the click event applied to them, but, you could also achieve this (if I understand correctly), by attaching the click event to the body and getting e.target. For example:    

    `$('body').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target); // target
        console.log($(this)); // body
    });`

Comment: This could also work. Good idea. To clarify: I want to make a chrome extension where you can select an element and compare it then to another element. Edit: This could be way better because I have to remove the selectors when I close the popup window from my extension...

Comment: Ok, I am kind of new to the etiquette here, but I guess I should update my answer for future generations?

Comment: oh yes. You should do this. I will also name you and your solution

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. In my `click` function I can just say `e.stopPropagation` to prevent jquery to walk up the tree/dom and fire also on the parents.

full solution:

```
$("body *").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Edit: Another Solution showed Pango. Instead of giving every Element on the page an EventListener you can give just the `body` Element an EventListener and then look after the target of the event. This will return you the correct clicked element.

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // target
    console.log($(this)); // body
});
```

This is a much cleaner solution because of only one EventListener. This is really important when you want to remove these without affecting eventListeners from other scripts. In my case, I have a toggle button that will activate an element-highlighter (like the from the inspector) with wich I can click on an element and then compare it to another one. So I need to deactivate/delete those listeners when I am done with selecting 2 elements. With this solution, it is much easier.